# Passing json object to an endpoint developed with spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have an endpoint I created using spring.io. My GetMapping declaration can be seen below

```
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Returns a pageable list of CustomerInvoiceProducts for an array of CustomerInvoices.",
        notes = "Must be authenticated.")
@EmptyNotFound
@GetMapping({
        "customers/{customerId}/getProductsForInvoices/{invoiceIds}"
})
public Page<CustomerInvoiceProduct> getProductsForInvoices(
        @PathVariable(required = false) Long customerId,
        @PathVariable String[] invoiceIds,
        Pageable pageInfo) {

        //Do something fun here
        for (string i: invoiceIds){
            //invoiceIds is always empty
        }
}
```

Here is how I am calling the url from postman and passing the data.

```
http://localhost:8030/api/v1/customers/4499/getProductsForInvoices/invoiceIds/
```

```
{
  "invoiceIds": [
    "123456",
    "234566",
    "343939"
  ]
}
```

My string array for invoiceIds is always empty in the for loop Nothing gets passed to the array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think a JSON request body will somehow populate a `@PathVariable` annotated parameter?

Comment: If I know, I won't have posted this question.

Comment: The mapping you have provided and the postman call you have provided do not match each other. There is no `/invoiceIds/` mapping.

Comment: Where is that? I don't get it

Comment: I'm trying to understand where your confusion comes from so I can tailor my answer to it. Why did you write the code this way? What did you intend for `@PathVariable` to do? And where did you expect the postman payload to go? Why? Please edit your question and include those details.

Answer (score -1):

The mapping you are using is this:

```
customers/{customerId}/getProductsForInvoices/{invoiceIds}
```

Both customerId and invoiceIds are Path variables here.

```
http://localhost:8030/api/v1/customers/4499/getProductsForInvoices/invoiceIds/
```

The call you are making contains customerId but no invoiceIds. Either you can pass the list in place of invoiceIds as String and read it as a String and then create a List by breaking up the List - which will be a bad practice.

Other way is to change your path variable - invoiceId to RequestBody.

Generally, Path Variables are used for single id or say navigating through some structured data. When you want to deal in a group of ids, the recommended practice would be to pass them as RequestBody in a Post method call rather than a Get method call.

Sample code snippet for REST API (post calls):

Here, say you are trying to pass Employee object to the POST call, the REST API will look like something below

```
@PostMapping("/employees")
Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
    //.. perform some operation on newEmployee
}
```

This link will give you a better understanding of using RequestBody and PathVariables - 
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/10/differences-between-requestparam-and-pathvariable-annotations-spring-mvc.html

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: I followed your suggestion and changed to RequestParam using a post. The error I got back was "Method not allowed" , "Request method Post not supported"

Comment: Hi, you can use this Spring link itself for creating REST APIs - https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: Sorry but doesn't he need to work with `@RequestBody` when posting JSON data?

Comment: That will also work, the second link i provided uses that.